# How to download 11g express edition on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: downloads, oracle

I can not download the Oracle DB 11g express edition on Ubuntu Server. Can anybody help with detailed terminal instruction or any other way.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't download"? What problem are you facing exactly?

Comment: oracle DB 11g express edition is only available in 64bit, and in .rpm format only.  You have to be running server 64bit, and convert the .rpm to .deb.

Comment: @Adel Abdellatif **Ubuntu**, **Ubuntu Server**, not *Ubunto*...

Answer (score 0):

Its a huge process . you can find it here.

you can download the oracle from here 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen

link 1 :http://www.makina-corpus.org/blog/howto-install-oracle-11g-ubuntu-linux-1204-precise-pangolin-64bits

link 2: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2461988